# EF6 and MSTest in TeamCity: Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance

Tags: entity-framework, teamcity, mstest, localdb

I've run into some issues with MSTest when they're run inside teamcity. When I run them inside VisualStudio on local machine, everything works good.

> [08:05:21][ProjName.Data.Tests.HistoryTableHandlingTest.HistoryProgressTest] **Class Initialization method ProjName.Data.Tests.HistoryTableHandlingTest.Init threw exception.** System.InvalidOperationException: System.InvalidOperationException: **The 'Instance' member of the Entity Framework provider type** 'System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.**SqlProviderServices**, **EntityFramework.SqlServer**, Version=**6.0.0.0**, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' **did not return an object that inherits from 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices'**. **Entity Framework providers must inherit from this class and the 'Instance' member must return the singleton instance of the provider.** This may be because the provider does not support Entity Framework 6 or later; see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=260882 for more information..

Here's my app.config for MSTest project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Another thing that I'd like to mention is, that I don't use EntityFramework library from NuGet, but it's clone EntityFramework.HierarchyId (it can be found in NuGet as well).

Comment: Can you try using the standard EntityFramework library to see if the issue still occurs? It might be helpful to rule that out first.

Comment: Since I use HierarchyId in my code, this could be a problem...

Answer (score 0):

After I rewrote all tests to NUnit, I got the same results.
But it seems, that the main reason of this behavior was, that on the build agent MS Sql Server Express wasn't installed properly.
When I re-installed latest version of SQL Express, everything started to work as a sharm. It seems that system was missing some drivers or libraries for LocalDB.

I hope that this will help someone else.